# Looping a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a really cool script, [Typer](http://aaroncordova.xyz/typer), to simulate a typewriter effect, but, is not included on its methods to loop the animation once it ends. 
Does anybody knows how it can be done?

```
typer('#rotating')
.cursor({block:true,blink:'hard',color:'#EB312A'})
.line('some line')
.pause(5000)
.back('all')
.continue('Other line');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  typer('#rotating')
  .cursor({block:true,blink:'hard',color:'#EB312A'})
  .line('some line')
  .pause(5000)
  .back('all')
  .continue('Other line');
}, 10000);
```

Where 10000 is the number of milliseconds between two calls of the passed in function (of course, you will have to specify it according to the duration of your animation).
`setInterval` is a native function that allows you to call a function periodically.

Hoping this will help you ;)

**EDIT**

Typer creates a new div inside your target `#rotating` when it is started.
That's why when you start it multiple times, you get duplicate content. To prevent that, just erase the content of the target div before restarting typer, like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  document.querySelector('#rotating').innerHTML = null; //This clears the content of rotating.
  typer('#rotating')
  .cursor({block:true,blink:'hard',color:'#EB312A'})
  .line('some line')
  .pause(5000)
  .back('all')
  .continue('Other line');
}, 10000);
```

**EDIT 2**

To make it start directly, simple enough:

```
var startTyper = function(){ 
  document.querySelector('#rotating').innerHTML = null; //This clears the content of rotating.
  typer('#rotating')
  .cursor({block:true,blink:'hard',color:'#EB312A'})
  .line('some line')
  .pause(5000)
  .back('all')
  .continue('Other line');
};
startTyper();
setInterval(startTyper, 10000);
```

The only thing left to you is to adjust 10000 to the duration of your animation!

Comment: thanks for your quick reply @sjahan, but what happens with setInterval is that the function duplicates itself (appears more than one time) instead of starting again.

Comment: That's weird, i suppose it is specific to how typer internally works. I'm gonna give it a try and send you some feedback here!

Comment: @JuanPabloContreras I updated my answer, it should work now ;)

Comment: well, I appreciate your effort, really! but the animation takes 10 seconds to start, although it loops when it reaches the end, shouldn't have to wait for the setInterval timer to start... but i'm really thankful for your work!

Comment: @JuanPabloContreras i've made an edit 2! It should fit your need, i hope!